# Why doesn't Redis work with my Rails application?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis, ruby-on-rails-6, actioncable, redis-rails

I'm currently using Rails 6 and Linux mint Cinnamon 20.2, and I have problems with Redis configuration / setupping in my Rails application.
My problem is that my ActionCable doesn't work well.

I would like to build a real time chat app, I created a channel, called "Room".
Here how my room_channel.js file looks like:

```
import consumer from "./consumer"

consumer.subscriptions.create({ channel: "RoomChannel", room_id: 3 }, {
connected() {
   console.log('Connected successfully!')
},

disconnected() {
   // Called when the subscription has been terminated by the server
},

received(data) {
   console.log(data)
}
});
```

Here's my room_channel.rb:

```
class RoomChannel < ApplicationCable::Channel
def subscribed
   stream_from "room_channel_#{params[:room_id]}"
end

def unsubscribed
   # Any cleanup needed when channel is unsubscribed
end
end
```

Here's the important segment of my messages_controller.rb file (The ActionCable command is the important):

```
def create
   @message = Message.new(message_params)

   @message.user = User.generate

   @message.save

   ActionCable.server.broadcast("room_channel_#{@message.room_id}",{message:"hello"})

end
```

When I join to Room 3 (3 is the ID of that room), I get my "Connected successfully" message, but when I send a message, it doesn't output "hello" in the console. It means it doesn't receive successfully datas, right?

What can i do with Redis to be able to receive data?

Finally, I changed the development section of my config/cable.yml file to, but it doesn't solved anything :(.

```
development:
   adapter: redis
   url: redis://localhost:6379/1
```

Anybody can help me out with this?
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Is redis running? try `redis-cli` in your terminal and/or `ps aux | grep 6379`

Comment: Do a console log in the `disconnect` method of `room_channel.js`. It might be instantly disconnecting due to some reason. Check the rails server logs for that.